# Fujifilm X100V X Raw Studio connection issues with v3.01 firmware

Tags: raw, fujifilm, fujifilm-x100, fuji

I use X Raw Studio 1.20.0.0 on MacOS and X100V with the latest 3.01 firmware.

When I open a folder having a .RAF files created with older firmware (2,13, 3.00). Everything works as expected. The camera connects and I'm able to convert raw files.

When I open a folder having a .RAF files created with 3.01 firmware, the app often crashes or shows "waiting for camera to connect" on the upper left corner. Also camera crashes as well, I'm not able to switch off with the normal on/off switch, I have to remove the battery.

Is there any solution for this issue?